# Layover in Istanbul

Tags: visas, istanbul

I will be going to Vienna via Istanbul [Turkish airlines] and I have 2 layover options. The first option is a 1-hour 40-minute layover and the second is a 6-hour layover.

I am keen on choosing the first option, but I am concerned about flight delays. If I choose the second option then I will be spending 6 hours in the airport.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is a 1-hour 40-minute gap between flights good enough?
2. Will I be allowed to enter Istanbul as I will have a valid Schengen visa?

Comment: Where is your first flight coming from, and what is your nationality?

Comment: Turkey treats transit arrivals differently depending on what country they are coming from, so as @jpatokal has already asked knowing what country you are arriving from matters in this case

Comment: My nationality is Indian and my flight will be coming from Delhi.

Comment: @Doc "Turkey treats transit arrivals differently depending on what country they are coming from". Everyone can Transit airside for 24 hours visa-free

Comment: @Crazydre Transit passengers arriving from some countries (regardless of citizenship) are allowed proceed directly to the departure area, whilst those from others origins must pass through transit security - which can add an hour or more at some times of day.

Comment: @Doc I see, didn't know that. I've always had to clear security arriving from BSL, CPH and ZRH

Answer (score 5):

If both of your flights are on the same reservation, a flight delay is the airline's responsibility.  If you choose the first option and miss the flight, Turkish will rebook you on the second flight.  In fact, this happened to me just two months ago when I missed a Turkish Airlines connection in Istanbul because of a delayed departure of my incoming flight.

So there's no reason for you to choose the later flight simply to avoid the possibility of missing the first flight.

Of course, if the flight is delayed so much that you miss the first flight, you won't be spending six hours in the airport, but more likely four.